# How to convert a String into a Class reference

Tags: c#

I have the string class name and I want to convert it to a class reference

```
if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()] != null)                                     
{
    (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()] as PC_01).accept();
}
```

I want use string `"PC_01"` instead of class `PC_01`.

Comment: [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are want to express the type of an object as string, you can do it with help of Type class, and use dynamic to invoke a method of this instance.

```
object obj = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()];
Type t = Type.GetType("myNamespace.PC_01, myAssembly");

if (obj.GetType() == t)
{
   ((dynamic)obj).accept();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Activator` class. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Activator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Ivan, for the future: it's a good practice to post a little code sample in your answer, not just a link.